# Changing a C/++ OpenCV program to CUDA from video stabilization program

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, image-stabilization

I am doing a C++ video stabilization/ anti-shaking program which:
- Gets points of interest on the frame of reference (using FAST, SURF, Shi-Matoshi or SIFT, might try a few more)
- Calculate the Lucas-Kanade Optical flow with calcOpticalFlowPyrLK
- Gets the homography matrix
- Corrects the shaking image using warPerspective (see code below)

```
//Calculate the Lucas Kanade optical flow
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(original, distorted, refFeatures, currFeatures, featuresFound, err);   

//Find the homography between the current frame's features and the reference ones's
if(homographyRansac){
    homography = findHomography(currFeatures, refFeatures, CV_RANSAC); /*CV_RANSAC: Random sample consensus (RANSAC) is an iterative method to
    estimate parameters of a mathematical model from a set of observed data which contains outliers */
}else{
    homography = findHomography(currFeatures, refFeatures, 0);
}


//We use warpPerspective once on the distorted image to get the resulting fixed image
if(multiChannel){
    //Spliting into channels        
    vector <Mat> rgbChannels(channels), fixedChannels;
    split(distortedCopy, rgbChannels);
    recovered = Mat(reSized, CV_8UC3);
    //We apply the transformation to each channel
    for(int i = 0; i < channels; i ++){
        Mat tmp;
        warpPerspective(rgbChannels[i], tmp, homography, reSized);
        fixedChannels.push_back(tmp);
    }
    //Merge the result to obtain a 3 channel corrected image
    merge(fixedChannels, recovered);
}else{
    warpPerspective(distorted, recovered, homography, reSized);
}
```

If you have any alternative to my stabilization solution, feel free to say so, but it's not this thread's topic.

Since all this takes a lot of time (around 300ms per frame on my i5 computer, so a VERY long time for a 30 min video) I am considering using CUDA to speed things up. I've installed it and go it working, however I'm not sure as to how to proceed next. I've done some test and I know the most time consuming operations are getting the optical flow and the frame correction using respectivly calcOpticalFlowPyrLK and warpPerspective. So ideally, at least at first,  I would only use the CUDA versions of these two function, leaving the rest unchanged.

Is this possible? Or do I need to re-write everything?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use built-in CUDA accelerated video stabilizer in OpenCV 3.0. Create an object of `OnePassStabilizer` class and set its motion estimator to `KeypointBasedMotionEstimatorGpu`. Just include `opencv2/videostab.hpp` in your code.

Comment: I'll give it a try and come back to you, thanks!

Comment: Could you help me out and elaborate a bit, I'm afraid I have no idea on how to proceed

Comment: Check my answer for OpenCV video stabilization example.

Answer (score 4):

Since OpenCV 3.0, a CUDA implementation of video stabilization is available. It is recommended to use the already available implementation instead of writing your own unless you are sure that your version would be better or faster.

Here is a minimal code demonstrating how to use the OpenCV video stabilization module to stabilize a video.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videostab.hpp>

using namespace cv::videostab;

int main()
{
    std::string videoFile = "shaky_video.mp4";

    MotionModel model = cv::videostab::MM_TRANSLATION; //Type of motion to compensate
    bool use_gpu = true; //Select CUDA version or "regular" version

    cv::Ptr<VideoFileSource> video = cv::makePtr<VideoFileSource>(videoFile,true);
    cv::Ptr<OnePassStabilizer> stabilizer = cv::makePtr<OnePassStabilizer>();

    cv::Ptr<MotionEstimatorBase> MotionEstimator = cv::makePtr<MotionEstimatorRansacL2>(model);

    cv::Ptr<ImageMotionEstimatorBase> ImageMotionEstimator;

    if (use_gpu)
        ImageMotionEstimator = cv::makePtr<KeypointBasedMotionEstimatorGpu>(MotionEstimator);
    else
        ImageMotionEstimator = cv::makePtr<KeypointBasedMotionEstimator>(MotionEstimator);

    stabilizer->setFrameSource(video);
    stabilizer->setMotionEstimator(ImageMotionEstimator);
    stabilizer->setLog(cv::makePtr<cv::videostab::NullLog>()); //Disable internal prints

    std::string windowTitle = "Stabilized Video";

    cv::namedWindow(windowTitle, cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while(true)
    {
        cv::Mat frame = stabilizer->nextFrame();

        if(frame.empty())   break;

        cv::imshow(windowTitle,frame);
        cv::waitKey(10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One last question, like I said I have OpenCV 3.0 and CUDA installed and I've added cuda.lib and cudart.lib to the linker. If I take a look at the global_motion.hpp the condition for using KeypointBasedMotionEstimatorGpu is 
#if defined(HAVE_OPENCV_CUDAIMGPROC) && defined(HAVE_OPENCV_CUDA) && defined(HAVE_OPENCV_CUDAOPTFLOW)
I can't seem to find the cudaimproc.h nor the cudaoptflow.h, and therefore I get an error with the GPU keypointsBasedmotion. What am I doing wrong? Thanks again

Comment: The opencv 3.0 binaries available in the default distribution are compiled without CUDA support so `HAVE_OPENCV_CUDA` is not defined and CUDA headers are missing. You must compile and build OpenCV from source using cmake.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll give it a try. However even if I try building the short code above I get LNK2005 "already defined" and LNK2019 "unresolved external symbol" due to the 4 definitions:
 cv::Ptr<VideoFileSource> video = cv::makePtr<VideoFileSource>(videoFile,true);
    cv::Ptr<OnePassStabilizer> stabilizer = cv::makePtr<OnePassStabilizer>();

    cv::Ptr<MotionEstimatorBase> MotionEstimator = cv::makePtr<MotionEstimatorRansacL2>(model);

    cv::Ptr<ImageMotionEstimatorBase> ImageMotionEstimator;

I have no header files. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: Okay so after some searching I am still at the same point. I have some linker error for some reason (LNK2005 "opencv_core300d.lib(matrix.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)" and LNK 2019). To solve the first one I used this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148652 but to no avail and for the second one I have no idea what to do